# Nest Camera Devices returing RTSPS stream URL - Not able to play rtsps: stream

Tags: flutter, camera, video-streaming, rtsp, nest-device-access

Anybody having idea how to play **RTSPS** stream in Flutter/Android Player. I am fetching Stream URL from Nest Camera API device, But it returns **RTSPS** Stream URL which is not playable. Can Anyone Guide me how to play it, Just for INfO its **RTSPS** url stream not **RTSP**?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following library for playing RTSPS streams however I'm experiencing a `Read timed out` error when attempting to play the rtsps:// stream returned from the Google Nest API.

https://github.com/alexeyvasilyev/rtsp-client-android

I would be very interested to know if this library works for you or if anyone has managed to play these rtsps streams on Android or iOS.

Comment: We reported this issue to the Nest team and all of a sudden one of our RTSPS streams is working when using the client I mentioned in this ticket. It is crashing though with an AudioCodec related issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you please Confirm how does this streams start working. Does the Nest team gave you any client or access to play the rtsps streams?

Comment: It just started working by itself, we didn't make any code changes, perhaps the Nest team did? However, it will still only work when using the specific RTSP client mentioned in my post.  I tried VLC and other players again after it began working but none will play it. I believe there is an issue with the Nest stream in that it claims to have an Audio track, however, there is no audio data, so the RTSP client will eventually crash with a low-level codec error. Disabling audio when creating the player means that it will maintain a video, based on our testing.

Comment: FYI, an update from the Nest Team:

It is, technically, an RTSPS stream, although I'm not sure if that makes a lot of difference. There are few clients that seem to play it correctly.  Some RTSP players won't/can't handle a RTSPS stream.

One issue we had in the past was needing to rebuild ffmpeg to allow for longer URLs as our media URLs are very long ... If you get error messages from ffplay you may have to rebuild with the following change:

Edit the line 318 of libavformat/rtsp.h, by changing the control_uri size to 2048.